# The problem with AyncFIFO with two clock sources written in Chisel 5.0

Tags: chisel, chiseltest

I wrote a AsyncFIFO in Chisel. Since Chisel-tester doesn't support multiple clock source, I wrote another shell to encapsulate the fifo. However, I encountered a problem in testing the empty condition.

My circuit has a decoupled input "read": io.read.ready is provided by the tester, and io.read.valid is the inverted empty signal. If the cache is empty, then io.read.valid is low to prevent more reading. At the same time, io.read.valid and io.read ready are connected to an incrementor to find the correct address: only when both are high, will the incrementor increment.

Now the strange thing is below:
[The waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdJwk.png)

After io.read.valid falls, the incrementor still increments additional period until it stops. (Which is not expected)

Chisel code of this part is below:

```
    val (read_addr, read_wrap) = (withClock(io.read_clock)) {
        Counter(0 until depth << 1, enable = (io.read.valid && io.read.ready))
    }
```

and the compiled Verilog is below:

```
  assign _full_T = write_addr - read_addr;  // src/main/scala/3_5_object_oriented_progrmming.scala:73:26, src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Counter.scala:61:40

......

  always @(posedge io_read_clock) begin // src/main/scala/3_5_object_oriented_progrmming.scala:30:16
    if (reset)  // src/main/scala/3_5_object_oriented_progrmming.scala:30:16
      read_addr <= 5'h0;    // <stdin>:45:3, src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Counter.scala:61:40
    else if ((|_full_T) & io_read_ready)    // src/main/scala/3_5_object_oriented_progrmming.scala:57:61, :73:{26,39}
      read_addr <= read_addr + 5'h1;    // <stdin>:45:3, src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Counter.scala:61:40, :77:24
  end // always @(posedge)
```

***Update: I had upload the full waveform, code, testbench (Since ChiselTesters doesn't support multiple clock sources at the top, I encapsulate it inside another module so that there is only one clock source), and the compiled Verilog: [OneDrive Link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmC5Wnm8o9sPivklm4Mdpv3J6MOGSA?e=DsoaPY)***

Comment: Could you update your waveform so that it shows the io_read_clock signal? Otherwise it is hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: @KevinLaeufer I had edited my question with full waveform and (for replication), the code and testbench I wrote for this module.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sources, this code

```
always @(posedge io_read_clock) begin
  // ...
  end else if (_T_1) begin 
    read_addr <= _wrap_value_T_3; 
  end
end
```

It is equivalent to

```
wire [4:0] _full_T_1 = write_addr - read_addr;
wire  _T_1 = io_read_valid & io_read_ready;
wire  empty = _full_T_1 == 5'h0;
assign io_read_valid = ~empty;

always @(posedge io_read_clock) begin
  // ...
  end else if (((write_addr - read_addr) != 5'h0) & io_read_ready) begin
    read_addr <= read_addr + 5'h1; 
  end
end
```

Along with the fact that `write_addr` is clocked not by a `io_read_clock`, it leads to a race condition in between pointers. You should recheck your design on the topic of what you are trying to synchronise with the Gray encoder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have already found the problem. I  synchronize the condition with the right clock, and this never happens again. For this specific question, I want to talk a little more: In fact, both `io_read_clk` and `io_write_clk` are got from main clock, as what I said due to the limitation in chisel simulator. Thus, the race condition is not possible to happened physically if the condition is always evaluated at the posedge. Why does it still occur in the simulator?